# Using write()/read() on UDP socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

According to the man pages:

> The only difference between send() and write(2) is the presence of flags.  With a zero flags argument, send() is equivalent to write(2). Also, the following call send(sockfd, buf, len, flags); is equivalent to sendto(sockfd, buf, len, flags, NULL, 0);

and

> The recv() call is normally used only on a connected socket (see connect(2)) and is identical to recvfrom() with a NULL src_addr argument.

Also,  if I'm not wrong (couldn't find it in the man pages), `recv` with `flags == 0` is equivalent to `read` (analogue to `write` and `send`).

---

So:

- does this mean, that using `read`on a UDP socket is perfectly fine (if I don't need the `src_addr`)?
- is there a way to use `write` on UDP socket (as now I set the destination address in `sendto`'s `dest_addr` parameter)?

Comment: @admdrew - why not? There's nothing C++ specific here (except my unnecccessary comment about the `socket_connection` class, which is absolutely irrelevant)

Comment: Yes, `socket_connection` was what I was confused about.

Comment: @KirilKirov C has no scope resolution operator ( `::`), only C++ does.

Comment: @black - true, point taken.

Answer (score 7):

- Using `read()` on a UDP socket is perfectly fine if you don't need the source address.
- You can use `write()` if you `connect()` the UDP socket to the destination.

Comment: "you can use write() if you connect() the UDP socket to the destination." 
We don't connect UDP sockets, right ?

Comment: @AbhishekSagar Wrong. You can connect a UDP socket to a target, in which case it only sends to and receives from that target.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, if I'm not wrong (couldn't find it in the man pages), ::recv
>   with flags == 0 is equivalent to ::read (analogue to ::write and
>   ::send)

Yes it is correct if the file descriptor is a socket: `send`/`recv` will fail otherwise with EBADF.
And it is also true that in a connection-oriented model `send` is equivalent to `sendto` and `recv` to `recvfrom` with NULL `sockaddr *` because the protocol *already* provides them.

With UDP, however, there's no connection so a call like this:

```
// assume fd to be an UDP socket
write(fd, buff, bytes)
```

would not make sense as no destination is provided (EDESTADDRREQ). 
Instead, when you read a packet, you know where it is coming from and you may want to use that IP in case something looks wrong, for istance.

My advise is:

- Use `send`/`recv` if you're in a connection oriented mode e.g. TCP
- Use `sendto`/`recvfrom` *mainly* for connectionless communications e.g UDP
- Use `write`/`read` if you will not specify any flag **and** for raw I/O (the aforementioned functions may be consider as higher level ones)

I would not advise a single class which handles both protocols but rather two specialized ones; don't mix the protocols.

Comment: I totally agree with the advices, I think in the same way, but I was tempted to use something very, very similar (almost the same), which already exists and has been tested for years. +1, I'll wait a bit more for other comments/answers.

Comment: You can connect a UDP socket to a target, in which case you can use `send()` and `write()`. Third bullet point contradicts earlier statements. Answer is not correct.